# Need help storing additional registration info in register.aspx

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am trying to create a custom profile to store additional registration info. With reference to another SO thread, I create a custom profile class, AccountProfile.cs, aside from the problem described below, I am not sure if I am doing the entire thing correctly, any help is appreciated, thanks:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Project
{
    public class AccountProfile : ProfileBase
    {

        static public AccountProfile currentUser
        {
            get
            {
                return (AccountProfile)
                       (ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName));
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return ((string)(base["FullName"])); }
            set { base["FullName"] = value; Save(); }
        }

        public string MailingAddress
        {
            get { return ((string)(base["MailingAddress"])); }
            set { base["MailingAddress"] = value; Save(); }
        }

    }
}
```

In the createuserwizard1_CreatedUser handler, I tried the following to store the FullName and Mailing Address after the user's registration but it throws me "a Object reference not set to an instance of an object." pointing to this line while debugging:

```
return (AccountProfile)
       (ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName));
```

Register.aspx code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    }

    protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(RegisterUser.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

        //Get the profile of the user by finding the profile by name        
        AccountProfile.currentUser.FullName = RegisterUser.UserName;

        TextBox oUserAddress = (TextBox)RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("MailingAdd");
        AccountProfile.currentUser.MailingAddress = oUserAddress.Text ;

        string continueUrl = RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(continueUrl))
        {
            continueUrl = "~/";
        }


        MyShoppingCart usersShoppingCart = new MyShoppingCart();
        String cartId = usersShoppingCart.GetShoppingCartId();
        usersShoppingCart.MigrateCart(cartId, RegisterUser.UserName);

        Response.Redirect(continueUrl);

    }
```

this is my web.config:

```
<profile inherits="project.AccountProfile">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
            <add name="FullName"/>
            <add name="MailingAddress"/>
         </properties>
    </profile>
```

Comment: What does `Membership.GetUser()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I actually need to add a get profile method in the `AccountProfile` class

```
public virtual AccountProfile GetProfile(string username)
{
    return ((AccountProfile)(ProfileBase.Create(username)));
}
```

and then append the additional fields to the newly registered user:

```
// Get profile of registered user
AccountProfile customuserProfile = (AccountProfile)AccountProfile.Create(RegisterUser.UserName, true);

// update these custom fields to him/her
customuserProfile .FullName = RegisterUser.UserName;
customuserProfile .MailingAddress = ((TextBox)  RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("MailingAdd")).Text;
customuserProfile .Newsletter = chkValue;

customuserProfile .Save();
```